# Filter table rows by combination of two filters

Tags: powerbi

I'm trying to filter a table by two slicers. In the table, one column refers to `Company` and the second refers to the `Country`. The two slicers refer to these same fields, respectively.

At present, filtering by only Company works - it filters the table to include all instances of that Company along with all its related Countries. However, filtering by Country doesn't work - it includes all instances of the Country, but also all instances of the matching Company regardless of Country. Filtering by both also doesn't work. Below are some illustrations.

[image: No filters selected]
[image: Company selected - correct result]
[image: Country selected - only rows containing 'Brazil' should show]
[image: Both filters selected - only 'Company A - Brazil' should show]

Is there a way to resolve this? Potentially in the data model?

[image: Data model - both relationships are many-to-many]

Answer (score 0):

You guessed correctly the issue is with how you have joined the tables, at the moment you have one disabled relationship and one one way relationship where prioritization filters supply-chain. The image below shows the aspect of the relationship you will need to change, filter direction should be single (supply_chain filters prioritization) and make this relationship active should be ticked
[image]

Ideally if you have two or more tables you need to filter, you would create an additional  table to use as a filter with unique values for each option and have a one way relationship where the new table filters the other tables. let me know if this helps

Comment: Thanks for your response. When trying one-to-many, it gives that cardinality isn't valid for the relationship. I'll try the additional table approach. Cheers